# Запрос в SQL, который вернет строку

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ребята всем доброго здравия, помогите пожалуйста, нужно написать запрос который вернет строку *Петр Сидоров 500 руб.* Еще новичок в этом деле.

Comment: и где же ему взять Пётр, если его нет в таблице?)

Comment: `select 'Петр Сидоров 500 руб'`

Comment: Петров Сидоров, ошибся)